# AlarmManager setRepeating disregards the interval

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I use this code to setup an alarm in our business application:

```
private void setupAlarm() {
    final Context c = getApplicationContext();
    final AlarmManager alarm = 
        (AlarmManager) c.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    final Intent i = new Intent(c, AlarmReceiver.class);
    final PendingIntent sender = 
         PendingIntent.getBroadcast(c, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    final long startFromNow = System.currentTimeMillis()+10000;
    final long timer = 5*60*1000;
    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, startFromNow, timer, sender);
}
```

I cannot understand why the interval for the alarm is not respected. First alarm starts after 10 seconds (as expected), afterwards it starts every 2 minutes and a bit (122 seconds to 127 seconds), which is wrong. The interval is 5 minutes, or am I wrong?

I use this exact code in a simpler application: one activity that sets the repeating alarm and the receiver just creates a log. There it works.

What could make the AlarmManager act so different?
  I have tried to:

- use `set()` and in the alarm receiver use another `set()` for over 5 minutes: launch at 2 minutes
- use `setInexactRepeating()` instead of `setRepeating()`: launch at 2 minutes

Any insight would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Immediate suggestion that comes to mind - make sure you don't set an alarm with the same intent and different value elsewhere. The intent need not be the same object, see the set methods documentation in AlarmManager.